# ContentControl not refreshing View when new ViewModel is created

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying to make an app using using MVVMLight that has a sidebar with buttons, each button shows a new usercontrol hosted in a ContentControl. When the user clicks the buttons in the sidebar (Show View1 / Show View2) it shows the views correctly.

My problems arise when the user has already shown a View (it could be View1 or View2 ), say View1 and click (Show View1)  ** again ** View1 controls remain with the same values and I would like to show the same view with all controls as if it had restarted. (I know that I could reset all controls within the user control (View1) but my application requires having a new instance of the view every time the button is clicked).

Somehow, in the same scenario when the user is in View 1, switch to view 2 and return to view 1, a new instance is created and shown as I would like. I would like to get the same result without the need to switch to view 2 and return.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of the issue:

> **ViewModelLocator.cs**

```
using CommonServiceLocator;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;

namespace SidebarApp.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
        /// </summary>
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            // Register viewmodels
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<View1ViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<View2ViewModel>();
        }

        public MainViewModel Main { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); } }

        public View1ViewModel View1Vm { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<View1ViewModel>(); } }

        public View2ViewModel View2Vm { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<View2ViewModel>(); } }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }
    }
}
```

> **MainViewModel.cs**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SidebarApp.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        // Commands
        public ICommand ShowView1Command { get; private set; }
        public ICommand ShowView2Command { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property that will cointain the current viewmodel to show
        /// ViewModelBase inplements ObservableObject class which imlements INotifyPropertyChanged
        /// </summary>
        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.ShowView1Command = new RelayCommand(ShowView1);
            this.ShowView2Command = new RelayCommand(ShowView2);
        }

        private void ShowView1()
        {
            // I tried this but it doesn't work
            //CurrentViewModel = null or View2ViewModel;

            CurrentViewModel = new View1ViewModel();

        }
        private void ShowView2()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new View2ViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

> **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SidebarApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SidebarApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="348.965" Width="560.683">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:View1ViewModel}">
            <local:View1View />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:View2ViewModel}">
            <local:View2View />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Command="{Binding ShowView1Command}">Show View1</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ShowView2Command}">Show View2</Button>            
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> **View1View.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SidebarApp.View1View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SidebarApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{Binding View1Vm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="LightPink">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Welcome to View 1" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Original text value"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Some boolean value"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> **View1ViewModel.cs**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace SidebarApp
{
    public class View1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public View1ViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

> **View2View.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SidebarApp.View2View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SidebarApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{Binding View2Vm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="LightCyan">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Welcome to View 2" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Some text in view2"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> **View2ViewModel.cs**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace SidebarApp
{
    public class View2ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public View2ViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

> **App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="SidebarApp.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SidebarApp" StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SidebarApp.ViewModel" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

For example I enter to the view1 and change the value of the textbox ("Original text value") to another value and I click again in Show View1 the text and everything in the usercontrol stays the same but when I switch to view2 and go back to view1 a new usercontrol is shown with his original values.

Comment: Have you tried returning a new ViewModel instance in the getter of your ViewModelLocator (instead of current instance)?

Comment: I've just tried not working. I just realized in debug mode that the first time I show the view1 it calls the contructor of View1View.xaml.cs but the second time is no longer called. I have no idea why. And a new instance of the viewmodel is created (wich is ok) I think the problem is in the view, not sure.

Comment: Any chance you have the project on github?

Comment: Sure I uploaded the project: https://github.com/alex-delacruz/SidebarApp

Comment: Ok. Will take a look and post if I discover something interesting.

Comment: Your `MainViewModel` doesn't raise a `PropertyChanged` event which is required to notify the view (`ContentControl `) that the binding source (`CurrentViewModel`) has changed.

Comment: I don't see how the code you've shown us can possibly work. Ensure you instantiate a new viewmodel rather than using the same instance.  If your ctor isn't called the second time then you've not got a new instance, because there is no mysterious magic will create a new instance without using the ctor. That new viewmodel will have the default valuees. Set the currentviewmodel to null before setting it to that new instance and ensure you raise propertychanged correctly. That will force a new instance of your view to be created by the datatemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This might feel like something of a workaround, but it works. Hopefully it will prove useful. (Obviously make same changes to View2View view/view model).

---

### ViewModelLocator.cs

```
 public View1ViewModel View1Vm { get { return new View1ViewModel(); } }
```

---

### MainViewViewModel.cs

```
 private void ShowView1()
 {            
    CurrentViewModel = new ViewModelLocator().View1Vm;           
 }
```

---

### View1View.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SidebarApp.View1View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SidebarApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d"                  
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="LightPink">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Welcome to View 1" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=View1Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Some boolean value" IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckBoxChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### View1ViewModel.cs

```
public class View1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        private string _view1Text;
        private bool _checkBoxedChecked;

        public string View1Text
        {
            get
            {
                return _view1Text;
            }
            set
            {
                _view1Text = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("View1Text");                
            }
        }

        public bool CheckBoxChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return _checkBoxedChecked;
            }
            set
            {
                _checkBoxedChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CheckBoxChecked");
            }
        }

        public View1ViewModel()
        {
            View1Text = "Original text value";
        }
}
```

Comment: It can be a solution but in my real application there is a datagrid which the user modifies (size of rows, width of columns etc) but when you want to reset the whole view the datagrid must be redefined as new without the modifications, changing only the data (viewmodel) only refreshes the data but not the control itself. I think I see the problem, apparently the content control needs a trigger that allows you to render the view again, without this you only recreate the view when it changes to another view, thanks for your help I appreciate it very much.